# How to getClass implicitly

Tags: scala, reflection, implicits

I'm writing a Scala wrapper over some Java code with a method signature like `method(cl: Class[_], name: String)` and many getClass methods in code looks not good:

```
Creator.create(getClass, "One")
Creator.create(getClass, "Two")
Creator.create(getClass, "Three")
Creator.create(getClass, "Four")
```

So can we somehow get enclosing class implicitly like `Creator.create("some name")`?

Comment: Can you explain better your question? I strongly suggest you to avoid using reflection....

Comment: @Edmondo1984 I'm interested in simple solution how to get class implicitly, and write method("some name") instead of method(getClass, "some name"), and the solution with ClassTags like method[SomeClass]("some name") doesn't look like a better aproach =)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 1.**

In general I warmly discourage reflection. However, if you really want to do it, in Scala 2.9.1 you can use Manifest

```
def create[T:Manifest](name:String) = {
   val klass:Class[_] = t.erasure
}
```

In scala 2.10 you should have a look to TypeTag.

**Answer 2.**

However, as I already said, the right approach would not be to use class but implicit builders

```
trait Builder[T]{
     def build(name:String):T
}

def create[T](name:String)(implicit builder:Builder[T]) = {
      builder.build(name)
}
```

in that way you can limit what you can create by importing only the right implicits in scope, you won't rely on reflection and you won't risk to get horrible RuntimeExceptions

**Post comment answer**

If your point is to avoid calling getClass at each invocation, you can do the following

```
def create(name:String)(implicit klass:Class[_]) {

}
```

And you can call it this way

```
implicit val klass1 = myInstance.getClass
create("hello")
create("goodbye")
```

Comment: Yea, i've also thought about ClassTags, but in this case, as you've sad, i have to use reflection and repeating method[Classname](param) isn't better then just call method(getClass, param)